# Remove Share,Embed from More options in list view

Tags: backbone.js, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-7, openerp-8

I am trying to remove `Share and Embed` from `List view`. I am using a module `web_hide_duplicate` module to remove same from `Form View`. It works fine. In list view it doesn't.

***.js**

```
 instance.web.ListView.include({

  load_list: function(data) {
      this._super(data);
      if (this.sidebar == undefined)
        return;
        var no_share = _.reject(this.sidebar.items.other, function (item) {
            return item.label === _t('Share');
            });

            this.sidebar.items.other = no_share;
        var no_embed = _.reject(this.sidebar.items.other, function (item) {
            return item.label === _t('Embed');
            });
            this.sidebar.items.other = no_embed;
      console.log('Tree view222',this.sidebar.items.other); // Here, only shows to record, Export and Delete. But in view all Options are listing.
  }

});
```

**Note:**

Now Drop down view look like,

**Label**        -->  **Function**

- Share  --->   Export Function
- Embed  --->   Delete Function
- Export --->   JS Error
- Delete --->   JS Error
  How can i do this?

Comment: Post the error please. Also which version of Odoo are you using?